# Display search and list filter in Mezzanine Pages admin interface

Tags: python, django, admin, mezzanine

Is there a simple way to display search and list filters in [Mezzanine's](http://mezzanine.jupo.org) admin interface for pages?

I tried putting the following in my application's admin.py, but the search and filters don't appear in the admin interface:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mezzanine.pages.models import Page, RichTextPage
from mezzanine.pages.admin import PageAdmin

admin.site.unregister(Page)

class CustomPageAdmin(PageAdmin):
    save_on_top = True
    list_display = ('title', 'publish_date', 'status')
    list_filter = ('title', 'publish_date', 'status')
    search_fields = ('title', 'content')

admin.site.register(Page, CustomPageAdmin)
```